# WinSCP to Docker Volume not listing all files and folders

Tags: docker, winscp

I have Docker on a remote server running Ubuntu. I use WinSCP to connect to volumes for file editing and FTP. Sometimes, WinSCP does not list all the folders and or files in a volume.

For example, on a WordPress container, I have a volume for /var. When I connect to the volume with WinSCP, I can click on www/html which takes me to the wp-content folder. When I click on that, I only see 3 folders listed: cache, plugins and themes. There should be several others - aiowps_backups, languages, updraft, uploads, upgrade. (aiowps_backups is the one I mainly want to get to).

Also when I click on any of the 3 folders that are shown, they come up empty even though I know there are files and folders inside them – I have checked this by accessing the container through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I figured this out, for some reason, the wrong name was attached to the volume.